# Increase according Variable JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables

First, thank you for the time you spend to help me.

Well my question is this: I have a form to make, depending on how you set the user agent to different results.

*eg*
1 Coin = 3 points,

I want that when the user put more than 10 coins, each coin is worth 4 points instead of 3, something like this:

10 coins = 40 points

Therefore it is a value that goes up depending on the amount

<10 Coins = 3 points

> 10 Coins = 4 points
>   50 coins = 5 Points

I have this code that it does is to add up to a fixed value, but I want that value is variable,

```
var conversions = { 
  'Monedas': {     
    'Puntos': 1, 
  } 
};
```

How could did?

A greeting and thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds like a math equation

Comment: You'll have to show the code that does the calculations. The code you've shown doesn't do anything.

Comment: Can you put an example of the piece of code that uses the conversions variable?

Comment: There is no calculation code whatsoever. What does your question have to do with forms or user agent?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check this code:

```
function Coin()
{
  var self = this;
  self.points = 0;
  function integerDivision(x, y){
    return (x-x%y)/y
    }

  self.AddCoins = function(amount)
  {
    self.points = self.points+amount*(3+integerDivision(amount, 10));
  }
}

var coin = new Coin();
coin.AddCoins(10);
alert(coin.points);
coin.AddCoins(20);
alert(coin.points);
```

Answer (score -3):

Ok, first of all, your language attribute on your script tag should not be equal to javascript. Instead, use `type="text/javascript"`

Then, if I understand your question, you could use `Math.floor` for what you need.

```
  var conversions = { 
   'Monedas': {
      'Coins': ###, // I assume that you'll have a value of coins here
      'Puntos': 1
   }, 
}; 

  var factor = Math.floor(conversions.monedas.coins / 10) + 2;
```

Then, you could set `Puntos` to `factor` times `monedas`.

```
  conversions.monedas.puntos *= factor;
```

If you need to find the value of the from the form's inputs, you could use jQuery's `.val` or `getElementsByClassName`, or `getElementById` and then use `.innerHTML` to find the value, I think.

Also, what language are you coming from? Portuguese?